# Optional parameter stored procedure with web service (.asmx) and Ajax call from front end

Tags: sql-server, ajax, web-services, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

I have a stored procedure with an optional parameter like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetPData
    (@StDt Datetime,
     @EndDt Datetime,
     @Process VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
     @Item VARCHAR(50) = NULL)
```

Then I have a method in my web service (`.asmx`) file like this:

```
public string GetProdData(string stdt, string enddt, [Optional] string process, [Optional] string item)
{
    return (ConvertDataToJsonString(result));
}
```

I call this method from my webpage like below:

```
var params = new Object(); 
params.stdt = myStDt; 
params.enddt = myEndDt; 
params.process = ??; 
params.item = ??;

$.ajax (   {
       url: /myWebService.asmx/GetProdData
       ,data:JSON.stringify(params);
       ,success:function(response){}
       ,error:function(response){}   } );
```

How to pass the optional parameter through Ajax, or is there any way to get result with full parameters or by not providing optional parameters?

Do I need to refine the web service method or any other way out...

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Ok marc_s, I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to achieve this by changing my WebService(.asmx) method as follows.

```
public string GetProdData(Dictionary<string, string> myObj)
{
       if(myObj["process"]!=null){ /*add myObj's member as parameter in SqlAdapters Command...*/}
}
```

And in FrontEnd (Page Level)Javascript/JQuery as follows:

```
            myObj.stdt = frDt;
            myObj.enddt = toDt;

            if (pro != '') {
                myObj.process = pro /*pro is local JS variable where Parameter will be stored and passed to WebService Method.*/
            } else { myObj.process = null;}
```